# Adding default command line options when opening a particular filetype

Tags: windows-7

I'd like to make it so that whenever I open a particular file type (by double clicking it in explorer) it always opens the associated program with particular command line options.

So, for example, when double clicking a .tex file I want it to not only open it with emacs (which is easy to set up just by going into "Open With"), but run emacs with the command line option "-fs".

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the easiest tool is [Nirsoft FileTypesMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

Launch it and find the extension you want to modify.

In the lower pane, find the action and modify it to either `emacs.exe -fs %1` or `emacs.exe %1 -fs`

... Assuming Emacs.exe is the program name. Also, having never used it, I am not sure what order to provide the arguments. `%1` is the file name, so use whichever one works.

Comment: I don't have the edit permission necessary to correct it myself but I think you mean "pane", not "pain". Not trying to be a grammer nazi or anything, just trying to help. +1

Comment: @Spooky Action - I have the knowledge, lack the grammar skills - I never take offence! ... I do try, but look through my other answers, you will find loads more!... But, I thought anyone can edit now :S

Comment: When I tried to edit the post it complained that my edit was too short? I wasn't sure if that's a permissions issue or just how the edit option works, either way I couldn't fix it myself.

Comment: Ahh - I had something similar when I tried to change something on Stack Overflow... I ended up adding white space to the end in order to allow the change. Good point and I will try to open a meta question about it.

Answer (score 8):

Looking under the hood at what Nirsoft FileTypesMan does, you can do the same thing manually as follows:

1. Look in

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ext
   ```

   at the `(Default)` value, for whatever file extension `.ext` you care about.  Call that value `{class_for_ext}`.
2. Look in

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{class_for_ext}\shell\open\command
   ```

   at the `(Default)` value.  That's the command line which Windows Explorer will run, and which FileTypesMan will let you edit.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I made a reg file script to for excel so it always opens in multiple exe instances vs the new default single instance. /X is the option for this in MS office apps. "excel.exe /X" in shortcut, and ".... excel.exe" /X "%1" in registry.

From win7:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xls_auto_file]
@=""
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,01,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xls_auto_file\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xls_auto_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xls_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" /X \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xlsx_auto_file]
@=""
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xlsx_auto_file\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xlsx_auto_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xlsx_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE\" /X \"%1\""
```